# how to stop redirecting from subdomain to primary domain?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I have a website- http://bulletfootball.com/ , I have some affiliates partners, they are sending me visitors to my site from some social media sites, for example: ao.bulletfootball.com is one of my affiliate partner's subdomain, made the subdomain's hosting destination same as the primary domain so that the subdomain can get everything(content,design etc.) from the primary domain. I create subdomain for my affiliate partners because I'd like to track how much views and ads click are getting from my affiliate partners.

Now the problem is, when users go to my site with subdomain like ao.bulletfootball.com  then when someone click on any link/posts/categories they redirect to primary domain.

There is a example what I actually wanted, look at this site- thecrazyfeed.com it's the primary domain. when you visit the site with subdomain like sm.thecrazyfeed.com then click on any link/posts/categories then look the links is coming with the subdomain, that is what exactly I want to do with my site.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript
text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-
icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try to change redirection through .htaccess

Comment: can you please let me know what to change exactly in .htaccess @anant

Comment: in htaccess redirection code is written for your subdomain site. just remove it or comment it and try. Actually try to comment and check once.

Comment: how do you create the links? in the <a href > are you using direct links? if not you can always try href="/linktowhereyourgoing" ensuring there is a slash at the start

Comment: look I have putted my .htaccess code in the description, can anyone please let me know what exactly to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is not with the redirection, but is in the way your links are rendered. Your links include the domain, for example `http://bulletfootball.com/category/league/`, when you should have links without the domain. For example, the previous link should be `/category/league/`.

This way, links will refer to the domain from where the page is downloaded, no matter which domain it is.

Comment: so, how to fix this issue in wp?

Comment: this seems to be what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472334/is-there-a-way-to-exclude-domain-from-link-generation-in-wordpress

Comment: I am not understanding on that :/

Comment: I am talking about subdomain, for example when you go to my ao.bulletfootball.com then click on any posts and then look at the url, it's changing to the primary domain.

Comment: That is because all your links are like http://bulletfootball.com/category/league/. If they where relative, like /category/league/, it would not redirect.

Comment: I installed the relative url plugin but now my homepage isn't loading, can you please check my site and let me know why it is doing like this?